# Ext JS 4.1 Grid CheckColumn deselects row with Checkbox Selection Model

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have a grid that is using CheckBoxSelectionModel as its selection model and I also have a Ext.ux.CheckColumn in the grid. If I select a row (check the box on the selection model), then click the checkbox in CheckColumn of the selected row, it deslects the row.

I looked for a listener to override, however, I didn't see one. Has any one else seen this behavior and how do I fix it?

```
Ext.require(['Ext.ux.CheckColumn', .....]);

Ext.create('Ext.panel.Grid', {
    .....,
    selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {}),
    columns:[
        {text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name'},
        ......,
        {xtype: 'checkcolumn', name: 'Can Edit', dataIndex: 'canEdit'}
    ],
    store: userStore
});
```

Comment: Please post your code for grid

Comment: I can't directly post my code... my system is not connected to the internet... but, I can retype the important bits, I assume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "stopSelection" property to your checkcolumn:

```
{xtype: 'checkcolumn', name: 'Can Edit', dataIndex: 'canEdit', stopSelection: false}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/XRmaV/

Comment: @ElGuapo One more version, with MULTI mode of selectionModel: http://jsfiddle.net/XRmaV/2/